# Eulerian directed graphs $2$-norm is 1

Tags: combinatorics, normed-spaces, algebraic-graph-theory, eulerian-path

I stumbled upon a strange question about eulerian graphs.

Let $G$ be a directed Eulerian graph.

*Prove* that it's normalized adjacency matrix $A$ has $\| A\|_2=1$.

It looked strange to me and I think I have found a counterexample

$$G=(\{1,2,3,4\},\{(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,4),(4,1)\})$$

$$
    A_G=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Clearly, $G$ is eulerian since $in-deg(1)=out-deg(1)=2$ and all the other degrees are $1$.

We also have $\|A_G\|=\sqrt{2}>1$.

Maybe we need $G$ to be $d$-regular? And if so how does it help?